# Mi acordeon de Bootstrap no funciona

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo varios problemas con mi acordeon de bootstrap:
No funciona correctamente, es decir, solo se abre el primer despeglable, cuando quiero abrir el segundo tambien se abre el tercero. Luego cuando quiero cerrar o abrir el primero, se me cierran o abren los otros dos. Es complicado! Que es lo que esta mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo HTML:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Playroom Main Page</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header">
            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Blog de notas
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#cienciasnaturalesapuntes">Ciencias naturales</li>
                <li><a href="#cienciassocialesapuntes">Ciencias sociales</li>
                <li><a href="bloginside.html">Matematica</li>
                <li><a href="#lenguapuntes">Practicas del lenguaje</li>
                <li><a href="#ingles">Ingles</li>
                <li><a href="#otros">Otros</li>
             </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
                <h2 class="accordion-header">
                  <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Examenes (titulo)
                  </button>
                </h2>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                  <div class="accordion-body">
                   //contenido     

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header">
                      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                        Tareas (titulo)
                      </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                      <div class="accordion-body">
                        //contenido
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
       </div>              
       </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Nota: Le saque el contenido del segundo y tercer acordeon para que el codigo no se muy largo. Muchas gracias por la atencion!

Comment: porque habras agregado php...

Comment: los divs se llaman iguales ;) <div id="collapseTwo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que cada button tiene una propiedad llamada: `data-bs-target="#collapseThree"` que hace referencia al id del elemento que colapsará o desplegará.

```
        <button
          class="accordion-button collapsed"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" //Id del ID colapsar/expander
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-controls="collapseTwo"
        >
          Examenes (titulo)
        </button>
        <div
            id="collapseTwo" //A este hace referencia el data-bs-target
            class="accordion-collapse collapse"
            data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
         >
        //Contenido
        <div>
```

Cada item del acordeón debe tener un id diferente, por lo que el data-bs-target del button también debe ser diferente a los demás, haciendo referencia al div que será colapsado/expandido.

También falta cerrar las etiquetas `<a>` dentro de los `<li>`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! En estos dias lo pruebo, muchas gracias!!

Comment: A las órdenes @Roxy012, no olvides si esto resuelve el problema marcar la pregunta como resuelta, de esa manera no quedará abierta para siempre y la gente sabrá que es una solución viable si pregunta por un problema similar.